# Can I update specified property in protocol extension?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create a protocol with some default methods that update a named property. Unfortunately I'm getting an error `Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable…`

```
protocol Weapon {
    var energy: Int { get set }
    var fireEnergy: Int { get }
    var rechargeRate: Int { get }

    func fire()
    func recharge()
}

extension Weapon {
    var fireEnergy: Int {
        return 10
    }

    var rechargeRate: Int {
        return 2
    }

    func fire() {
        guard energy >= fireEnergy else { return }
        energy -= fireEnergy  // <- Error Here
    }

    func recharge() {
        energy += rechargeRate // <- Error Here
    }
}

class PhaseCannon: Weapon {
    var energy = 0
}
```

If I change the methods to mutating as suggested, then I get an error at the point of use for the fire method. `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value…`

```
var weapons = [PhaseCannon()]

for weapon in weapons {
    weapon.fire() // <- Error here 
}
```

Can I not do this?

Comment: `PhaseCannon` is a class or a struct?

Comment: @Aaron Bratcher can you share Phase cannon class

Comment: using the keyword `mutating` at `-fire()` and `-recharge()` probably necessary here; on the other hand inside your iteration you cannot use mutating method on an immutable local type.

Comment: PhaseCannon class added

Answer (score 0):

Your second error is because **weapon** in for cycle is *let*. The fastest fix possible is you can change your code to:

```
var weapons = [PhaseCannon()]
var newWeapons: [PhaseCannon]

for weapon in weapons {
    var updatedWeapon = weapon
    updatedWeapon.fire() // <- Error here 
    newWeapons.append(weapon)
}
```

Comment: I've found that if I change the methods to mutating and then do the for loop as `for var weapon in weapons` it works properly. It's just odd that a class instance needs to be a var.

Comment: @AaronBratcher, awesome, it's even better then :)

Answer (score 0):

If refactoring your existing code permits, I would suggest turning PhaseCannon into a class rather than a struct.

Otherwise you could change your update loop like this:

```
for index in weapons.indices
{
   weapons[index].fire()
}
```